# php regex remove all non-alphanumeric and space characters from a string

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to remove all non-alphanumeric and space characters, I have this

```
$page_title = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", "", $page_title);
```

but it doesn't remove space characters and replaces some non-alphanumeric characters with numbers.

I need the special characters like puntuation and spaces removed.

Comment: `replaces some non-alphanumeric characters with numbers`? You aren't replacing anything you are removing it. What numbers are appearing? Maybe you have entities? Show `$page_title`, with `var_dump`.

Comment: Replace the entities first.

Comment: How do I replace the entities

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If all you want to leave all of the alphanumeric bits you would use this:

```
(\W)+
```

Here is some test code:

```
$original = "Match spaces and {!}#";
echo $original ."<br>";

$altered = preg_replace("/(\W)+/", "", $original);
echo $altered;
```

Here is the output:

> Match spaces and {!}#
>
> Matchspacesand

Here is the explanation:

1st Capturing group: `(\W)` matches any non-word character [^a-zA-Z0-9_]
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

Comment: `\s` is a subset of `\W`

Comment: Good catch @sln! Editing now.

Answer (score 2):

> I need the special characters like puntuation and spaces removed.

Then use:

```
$page_title = preg_replace('/[\p{P}\p{Zs}]+/u', "", $page_title);
```

- `\p{P}` matches any punctuation character
- `\p{Zs}` matches any space character
- `/u` - To support unicode

Comment: I have this in $page-title IDM, PPC & SEO T&Cs if I use the regex and echo $page-title I get this idmppc038seot038cs (I'm also making it lowercase) but what I want is idmppcseotcs

Comment: @ttmt `038` is the entity for ampersand, see first comment on your question +30 minutes ago, and update question.

Comment: @ttmt: As Chris suggested you should show output of `var_dump` in question and also show your expected output.

Comment: @ttmt - `$page_title = 'IDM, PPC &#038; SEO T&#038;Cs'; $page_title = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "", $page_title); // tolower = idmppc038seot038cs` So you would have to convert the entities first.

Comment: May be calling `strip_tags` before `preg_replace` may help

Comment: It is great that you drew attention to supporting Unicode strings.  I have found this to be an excellent resource concerning [Unicode Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).  Should it be `'/[\p{P}\p{Z}]+/u'` to delete any form of whitespace?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`preg_replace('/[^[:alnum:]]/', '', $page_title);`

`[:alnum:]` matches alphanumeric characters

Comment: `[:alpha:]` is alphabetic characters. `[:alnum:]` are alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @chris85 since he posted alphabetic first and alphanumeric after updating question

Answer (score 0):

Works good for me on Sublime and [PHP Regex Tester](http://www.phpliveregex.com/)

```
$page_title = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "", $page_title);
```

Comment: I think you want `\s` in that character class, `s` is going to be literal which the `a-z` covers.

Comment: nope, it dosn´t need it in that case becouse has the ^ at beggining, you can try it on http://www.phpliveregex.com/
(Sorry for my english, not native lenguage)

Comment: `s` is an `s` which is covered by the ranges. See https://regex101.com/r/vC1dD6/2, the whitespaces are matched.

Comment: you are right, i understood wrong when i run the test, the "s" does not do any function becaouse is already in the a-z range, the only left for the regex works (his regex) was removing the " " thx @chris85